# How can we integrate Latex with React or any other UI framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, latex

I want to create Latex.js with existing React project. There I have to create runtime environment for latex just like [playground](https://latex.js.org/usage.html#webcomponent). For which I am going through Latex documentation. In documentation I got code snippet which is not working for me. It is giving me an error `can not find module 'fs'` for `svgdom` package.

```
import { parse, HtmlGenerator } from 'latex.js'
import { createHTMLWindow } from 'svgdom'

global.window = createHTMLWindow()
global.document = window.document


let latex = "Hi, this is a line of text."

let generator = new HtmlGenerator({ hyphenate: false })

let doc = parse(latex, { generator: generator }).htmlDocument()

console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Thank you.